# Customizer API way function is_customize_preview() works only in main page?

Tags: theme-development, customization, theme-customizer

Dear wordpress developer,

Thanks for create incredible API like Customizer :) but I have little problem. In customizer preview view function: is_customize_preview() when I'm in home page return true but when I click on page in menu (I'm still in customizer view) this function return false. Why?

Regards
Michal

Comment: this is better to ask in the official core trac or IRC. There are no core developers that participate in continuous way here so no much point in suggesting here that things should be done differently.

Comment: I do this too but still no answer :(